# How do I pass a string as an argument name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

I have the following function:

```
def create_act(user, verb, fk_name=None, fk_value=None):
    fk = getattr(Action, fk_name)
    action = Action(user=user, verb=verb, fk=fk_value)
    action.save()
```

Action is a class. The class has multiple attributes, and I don't know at the beginning, which attribute will get a value.

I get the attribute name dynamic.

I want the kwarg `fk`, to be an actual attribute of the class action. FK can be account or company.

```
class Action(models.Model):

account = models.ForeignKey(Account, blank=True, null=True, related_name='activity', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
company = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank=True, null=True, related_name='activity', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

---

I found on the forums some answers but nothing relevant to me, or in python.
I saw some suggestion on other sites to use eval, but eval is not safe.

Comment: here is a helpful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave some example *values* and an example of what kind of call you want to emulate. Are you trying to say that `fk` in `Action(.., fk=...)` should be a variable value based on the `fk` variable, e.g. `Action(..., foo=fk_value)`?

Comment: @deceze more info added, is django I create an instance, and fk is a Foreign Key

Comment: Still rather unclear. You want the actual call to look like `Action(..., Account='foo')`? The most helpful thing would be if you showed us what the call would look like if you wrote it by hand.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `dict` unpacking with `**`. Note that -- if `fk_name` is the name of a `ForeignKey` -- `fk` will not be a string, but a `ForwardManyToOneDescriptor`. You'd probably still want to set the attribute named `fk_name`:

```
action = Action(user=user, verb=verb, **{fk_name: fk_value})
```

Comment: Dict unpacking is right, but the whole point surely is that `fk` *isn't* a string.

Comment: @DanielRoseman fk_name that is the argument of the initial function is a string, can I used directly without using getattr ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Well, it still shows which form can be used to achieve dynamic keyword assignment. OP's problem should be translatable into this.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to dynamically pass to the class creation a pair of attribute name and value, to do that, create a dictionary using the name/value attribute and pass it along using dictionary unpacking:

```
def create_act(user, verb, name, value):
    attrs = {name: value}
    action = Action(user=user, verb=verb, **attrs)
    action.save()
    return action
```