# Use variable in url_for in flask for parameter name

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have this code in my macro file for flask.

```
{% macro display_name(name, parameter, parameter_value) %}
<a href="{{ url_for('users_stats',parameter = parameter_value) }}">{{name}}</a>

{% endmacro %}
```

I am not able to set the value of parameter to what I pass in the function. It is coming as a plain text, How to fix this?

This is how I am calling the function.

```
  {{ display_name("Rahul", 'age', 15) }}
```

Comment: So you want to assign parameter `age` to value `15` and call `url_for`?

Comment: Yes, I want to assign age to 'parameter' and  15 to parameter_value

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47907268/how-do-i-pass-a-string-as-an-argument-name you can use kwargs and dict unpacking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try kwargs dict unpacking. I recommend research more info later.

```
{% macro display_name(name, parameter, parameter_value) %}
<a href="{{ url_for('users_stats', **{parameter: parameter_value}) }}">{{name}}</a>

{% endmacro %}
```

The point is creating `dict` where keys are names of parameters, values are values of corresponding parameters. Then unpack this dict via `**` operator to pass these parameters and values into function.